# Probability of choosing a square from a circle of points

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> 1. Twelve points are equally spaced on a circle. If $4$ of $12$
>      points are to be chosen at random, what is the probability that a quadrilateral having the $4$ points chosen as vertices will be square?
> 2. Sixteen points are equally spaced on a circle. If $4$ of $16$
>      points are to be chosen at random, what is the probability that a
>      quadrilateral having the $4$ points chosen as vertices will be square?

I can solve this for $8$ points, where 2 squares is possible out of ${_8\mathsf C}_4$ selections of 4 points. So, the probability comes $2/70$ = $1/35$. But I can't solve these two.

Comment: Have you sketched a figure, and tried to understand ?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that I could solve for 8 points, but couldn't solve for 12 or 16 points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(*We assume the points are labelled and distinct.*)

The first problem may be solved as follows: there are $\binom{12}4$ ways of choosing *any* four points on the circle. Of these, only three form a square, so the probability is
$$\frac3{\binom{12}4}=\frac1{165}$$
The second problem can be solved similarly, with $\binom{16}4$ ways to choose four points and four of these ways forming a square:
$$\frac4{\binom{16}4}=\frac1{455}$$

Comment: I understand now. one square is possible with 4 distinct points, and as we can have three 4 distinct points from 12 points, it is possible to form only 3 distinct square. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I detect a homework problem.

*Hint no. 1:* How many ways are there of choosing 4 points out of a total of 12 (16, respectively) points?

*Hint no. 2:* If you disregard rotations, there is really only one way of choosing 4 points on a circle in such a way that the points are the vertices of a square.